# Android background image does not change according to the view

Tags: android, xml, tags

I'm trying to put a background image for my app. I used two images for landscape view and portrait view.

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156000/in-android-background-image-does-not-change-when-orientation-does) question answers and it didn't help.

Here's my portrait view background.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background" >
```

Here's my landscape view background.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_land">
```

When I load my app in the portrait view, portrait background view displays and when I change the orientation to landscape the same portrait image stretches and displays. but, when I load the app in landscape view, landscape background view displays.

What should I do to change the background image when we change the orientation.

- Edit -

Activity from manifest.

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.NICT.nict.LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could point to the same resource in your layouts and place 2 resources in drawable folder.

1- Layouts

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background" >
```

2- Drawables

```
../res/drawable/background (Portrait default mode)
../res/drawable-land/background (Landscape mode)
```

Hope it works.

Comment: I have different layouts called, layout, layout-land, layout-large, layout-large-land, layout-small, layout-small-land, layout-sw600dp, layout-sw600dp-land, layout-sw720dp and layout-sw720dp-land. Should I create land drawable s to each drawable and put the landscape image to land drawable.

Comment: No matter how many layouts you have. If you create 2 resources in that folders, drawable and drawable-land, the background image changes automatically when orientation changes.

Comment: should I create only one drawable-land or create different drawables named drawable-hdpi-land, drawable-ldpi-land, drawable-mdpi-land, drawable-sw600dp-land, drawable-sw720dp-land and drawable-xhdpi-land to different screen sizes

Comment: It depends on your needs, if you want the same drawable for each land screen sizes, you must use only a drawable in drawable-land.

Comment: Okay. I'll proceed with your answer. Thanks

Comment: I created a folder called drawable-land and paste the land image inside that folder and renamed the image as background. Still the portrait image gets as the landscape image.

Comment: could you post your <activity> tag from manifest?, check android:configChanges property

Comment: ok... remove android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize", or check why you are using that propery.

Comment: removed the configChanges now working as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to overcome this problem,

1. Create a drawable-land inside res
2. Copy the landscape background image into that folder
3. Remove android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" from manifest

Now, background image loading perfectly without any errors.